# XmlDocument - load from string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    try
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath(".");
        doc.Load(path+"whatever.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
        return;
    }

    // Convert XML to a JSON string
    string JSON = XmlToJSON(doc);

    // Replace \ with \\ because string is being decoded twice
    JSON = JSON.Replace(@"\", @"\\");

    // Insert code to process JSON at end of page
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "SpaceJSON", "space_processJSON('" + JSON + "');", true);
}
```

Instead if of loading the xml from a file, how do I load it from a string?

Comment: Look up the [`XmlDocument` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx). You'll figure it out yourself very quickly.

Comment: `LoadXml()` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx

Answer (score 218, accepted):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(str);
```

Where `str` is your XML string. See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) for more info.

Comment: What about new XmlDocument(){ InnerXml = str }?

Comment: I think `LoadXml()` does more than just setting `InnerXml`. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlDocument.cs,774e340cfa235dc6