# get utf-8 geocode google map API Street address in asp

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am beginner in asp.net (c#) 
But i need to get the utf-8 address from latitude & longitude position
So i need to retrieve the address in fa language and i We've added language= fa to String map address.
but it retrieved the strange character 
this is my code:

```
public static void RetrieveFormatedAddress(string lat1, string lng1)
{
    static string baseUri = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&language=fa&sensor=true";
    string requestUri = string.Format(baseUri, lat1, lng1);

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(requestUri));
    }
}

static void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var xmlElm = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
    var status = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
                  where elm.Name == "status"
                  select elm).FirstOrDefault();
    if (status.Value.ToLower() == "ok")
    {
        var res = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
                   where elm.Name == "formatted_address"
                   select elm).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(res.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
        GetSMS getsms1 = new GetSMS();
        getsms1.retrunAdress(res.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error");
    }
}
```

And google returned me :

```
    طھظ‡ط±ط§ظ†طŒ طھظ‡ط±ط§ظ†طŒ ط®غŒط§ط¨ط§ظ† ط§ظ…غŒط±غŒ ط·ط§ط¦ظ…ظ‡طŒ ط§غŒط±ط§ظ†
```

How can i get the 'Farsi' language address from google?
Thank you

Comment: which (i.e. which variable) exactly is the string you quoted as the result? did you have a look at the result of the request in the browser to see whether it has any similarity with the string's content? you have requested the language in farsi (language=fa) - was this your intention? The result seems to contain some farsi-like characters, so it is not necessarily completely wrong. Try to see what happens if you use english, then switch back to farsi if necessary.

Comment: @RemigiusStalder  First,thanks for your comment.
and yes i need the farsi street language.
when i used language=en, then, i have received the english street address like in below:
"Tehran, Tehran, Amiri Taeme Street, Iran"

Comment: please answer all my questions...

Comment: What do you mean of i.e ? (you mean my browser)? And use the string request in browser and the result is correct fa language.

Comment: The result in the browser shows you what is returned by Google. I cannot verify anything as you don't provide coordinates of your test case. Which of the variables contains the result you quoted? Does it correspond to the intended part of the returned XML? If this is the case (and also your code works correctly in english), you can only supply a bug report to Google (don't ask me how to get Google to fix this). Otherwise you should query the returned XML in a different way to get exactly the part of it you require.

Comment: It seems there will be  some error in 
    var xmlElm = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
because when i use the google String addressi in browser then retruned the correct characters fa language. but after this line the characters make change to another unicode

Comment: @RemigiusStalder do you know another way to do this? like json

Comment: that's precisely what I'm thinking about. It looks to me as if the content of e.Result is a correct response in correct XML (i.e. the same as what you see in the browser). You need to extract the content of the first occurrence of GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address. I think, the Linq API you are using is overshooting (it provides an SQL-like interface to XML documents). A straight-forward approach would be to read the string into an XmlDocument, as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929653/xmldocument-load-from-string, then navigate along the XPath mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of searching on net and test a lot different codes, Finally i found the solution. My codes are right but only need the set UTF-8 Unicode on web-client object. So my code will change to this:

```
  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
       wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
       wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
       wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(requestUri));
    }
```

this will work in UTF-8 as well.