# Is There anyway to remove Ampersand prior to XmlDocument Load?

Tags: c#, xml

Here is my Code?

```
  XmlDocument rssXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

           // Load the RSS file from the RSS URL
           rssXmlDoc.Load("https://polsky.uchicago.edu/events/feed/");


                var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssXmlDoc.NameTable);
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("event", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL;Transform");

            // Parse the Items in the RSS file
            XmlNodeList rssNodes = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item", nsmgr);
```

I know that the XML has some elements that contain "&", and I also know that it is really not up to me to fix this bad RSS feed; however, I am not certain if they will comply. Is there anything I can do?

The following exception is thrown:

An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 138, position 26.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the problematic XML?

Comment: Can you give an example of where these ampersands are located? Inside the tags, or in the value elements?

Comment: This is the reported problem: `<title>Y Combinator Q&A at Tovala</title>`

Comment: Load the file into a string, clean string, load xml string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929653/xmldocument-load-from-string

Comment: I feel like I could scrub the XML if I can somehow get the XML into a string, but I cam not certain how to load the XML into a string. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fix that with an XML parser because it's invalid XML. & isn't allowed without being escaped.

You can however read in the bad XML as a string, do a string replace of `&` for `&amp;`, then process the string with your normal XML parser.

You can also bracket it in CDATA and get on with your life 8-)

PS. If you go with the first method, be sure to check for and handle the other "bad" characters like `<>"'` (less than, greater than, double quote, single quote)

Comment: Thank you so much, i am already working with the provider to fix the issue.

Comment: That's even better since it's broken for everybody, not just for you. They really shouldn't be sending out invalid XML.

Answer (score 1):

I use System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape() to take care of "XML encoding" requirements.  It works essentially the same as the System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode Encode/decode

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securityelement.escape